# Как загрузить фотографии на сервер отобразить это фото в html?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, freemarker

Решил изучать Spring boot на практике, посмотрел плейлист уроков канала let's code: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1g3kT0ZcSXt4_ZyJOshKJQ. В уроке он деплоил приложение на виртуальную машину, я в свою очередь решил на heroku. Но в этом веб приложении при добавлении сообщения, можно было к нему добавить фотографию, и соответственно автор канала сохранял фото в домашней директории. Конечно в моём случае это не подходит и мне нужно как-то загрузить фотографии на сервер, и затем это фото отобразить на страничке html. Искал ответ в интернете, нашёл пару англоязычных статей, но так и не получилось загрузить фото. Помогите пожалуйста, мне не важно пока что за технологию использовать, нужно просто чтоб работало загрузка на удалённый сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Писать код не стану, но объясню как.

1. Поскольку вы генерируете страничку на сервере, то вы генерируете

   <img src="/images/Image_UniqName.jpg" alt="my image text">
2. На сервере будите обрабатывать get запрос на Route("/images/*") который и будет возвращать картинку из базы данных. Т.е. У вас по существу должен быть сгенерирован `Image_UniqName.jpg` по которому вы однозначно вернете картинку из базы данных.